# Label component display issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

On the web page linked below I am trying to use labels to display a vertical list of items found under the heading 'What we specialise in!'. The default element is a span to display a label however multiple labels are stacking up on the same line which is not what I want to achieve visually, I actually desire each label to occupy an individual line instead. (Is this possibly to do with the `display: inline-block;` CSS rule?). Is there a change of markup or CSS property to assist with this?

http://openreachmarketing.co.uk/index.php

```
  <span class="odd label label-info">Accident Compensation</span>
  <span class="even label label-warning">PPI</span>
  <span class="odd label label-important">Buildings and Contents Insurance</span>
  <span class="even label label-info">Utility Switches</span>
  <span class="odd label label-warning">Car Loans</span>
  <span class="even label label-important">Solar Panels</span>
```

Here is the documentation for the bootstrap labels:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#labels-badges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You have `h4` for the heading!

```
<h4 class="heading">What we specialise in!</h4>
```

The **What we specialise in!** is behaving exactly as expected. But if you want that to be displayed like a `label`, then clear the styles for the `H4` there and give this mark-up.

```
<h4><span class="label">What we specialise in!</span></h4>
```

Or

```
<h4><span class="odd label label-info">What we specialise in!</span></h4>
```

The other things like: Accident Compensation PPI Buildings and Contents Insurance Utility Switches Car Loans Solar Panels, etc are behaving right.

#### CSS for multi line display!

```
.span4.margbot20 .label {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
}
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

#### Just Markup Change

```
<p><span class="odd label label-info">Accident Compensation</span></p>
<p><span class="even label label-warning">PPI</span></p>
<p><span class="odd label label-important">Buildings and Contents Insurance</span></p>
<p><span class="even label label-info">Utility Switches</span></p>
<p><span class="odd label label-warning">Car Loans</span></p>
<p><span class="even label label-important">Solar Panels</span></p>
```

Comment: Thank you Praveen, I am trying to make the following labels appear on separate lines - Accident Compensation PPI Buildings and Contents Insurance Utility Switches Car Loans Solar Panels, etc are behaving right

Comment: Yeah, you can do one thing. Use the code that I will be updating.